# How to find a specific table from my database with an sql script

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm a total beginner with sql / data base but i'm trying to learn on a fake data base.
My problem is that i want to find a specific Table from a Schemas and i only know that in the table name there's "CRH".
I've been searching on every tutorial but none of them seems to be working i'm probably doing something wrong like i don't have the right dependencies.I'm using data beaver and i didn't modified it after the download.
here's my code :

`SELECT * FROM SCHEMAS_NAME WHERE name LIKE '%CRH%'`

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The standard way would be to search `information_schema.tables`.

Comment: i'm working with dbeaver sorry

Comment: DBMS: Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc

Comment: oh so dbeaver isn't a DBMS right ? so idk how to see which dbms i'm using i guess i'm using the standard DBMS from dbeaver i'm really sorry i'm a total beginner

Comment: What does `select version()` give you? Or `select @@version` or `select * from v$version;`?

Comment: it gives me 4 rows : Oracle database 12c entreprise edition release, PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0, CORE 12.2.0.1.0, TNS FOR LINUX, NLSRTL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Oracle 12c DBMS so try this:

```
SELECT table_name FROM all_tables
WHERE table_name LIKE '%CRH%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your database is MS SQL Server: Try following code.

```
select * from sys.all_objects where type = 'U' and name like '%CRH%'
```

Comment: i'm working with dbeaver but i'll try this